# Have text flow around an object that can be moved by the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have a div that floats to the left, and some text that wraps around it.

I want to be able to move the div up and down with javascript.  As I do so, I want the text to flow around it (above it and below it as needed).

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve.  Something like how text might behave if you position an object in a word document.

I have already looked into it a bit, and the conclusion I am coming to is that it is only possible if the div is contained within the same parent element as the text.  If you want to move the div up and down, you would have to move its position within the text itself (e.g. take a sentence from behind and move it infront).

Doing something like giving it a top margin simply extends the block which text has to flow around, and making it position relative means that the text flows around its original position, and the relatively positioned div overlaps the text.  It all makes perfect sense, but makes it very difficult to achieve what I want.

Is there anything in html/css that might allow for what I want, or any plugin that does what I have described.

Thanks

Comment: Could be interessting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7601378/983992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcels link is v interesting actually.

I might be tempted to fudge it and get a close approximation, since its simple and gets you half way there.

http://jsfiddle.net/tromm/e3YHb/

```
var img = $('#whale');
var nextP = img.next();
var previousP = img.prev();

$('#move-down').click(function() {
    nextP = img.next();
    img.detach();
    img.insertAfter(nextP)
});

$('#move-up').click(function() {
    previousP = img.prev();
    img.detach();
    img.insertBefore(previousP)
});
```

Essentially moving the  through the s. in the fiddle i also floated the image so it almost-kinda-sorta looks like its doing what you expect. :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Looks like I will have to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was working on (if it is of any use to anyone).  It attempts to move the element though the text, checking offsetTop to see when it has actually moved to a new line (I only did the down motion).  I would then have moved on to figure out how to call this multiple times when dragging an element.  Too much effort for what I need (I would have to take into account elements within elements), and it looks like it will be in html one day anyway, so I will just accept Tom's solution.

```
function down(el) {
    var parentDiv = el.parentNode;
    var next = el.nextSibling;
    var prev = el.previousSibling;
    var match, word;

    var offset = el.offsetTop;

    while ((match = /^\s*\S+\s*/.exec(next.nodeValue)) !== null && el.offsetTop === offset) {
    word = match[0];

    if (prev === null) {
        prev = parentDiv.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(''), el);
    }

    prev.nodeValue += word;
    next.nodeValue = next.nodeValue.substring(word.length);
    }

    if (el.offsetTop !== offset) {
    return;
    }

    var nextDiv = findNextDiv(parentDiv);

    if (nextDiv === null) {
    return;
    }

    parentDiv.removeChild(el);

    if (nextDiv.firstChild === null) {
    nextDiv.appendChild(el);
    }
    else {
    nextDiv.insertBefore(el, nextDiv.firstChild);
    if (el.offsetTop === offset) {
        down(el);
    }
    }
}

function findNextDiv(el) {
    var next;
    while ((next = el.nextSibling) !== null) {
    if (next.tagName === 'DIV') {
        return next;
    }
    el = next;
    }
    return null;
}
```