# Place element at specific px, but have text flow around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I place an element (such as an image) at a specific px location on a page and then have text flow around it?

With JS/jquery as necessary.

I did see this [Have text flow around an object that can be moved by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136039/have-text-flow-around-an-object-that-can-be-moved-by-the-user). It didn't have an answer, but it's a few years old so...

EDIT: Let's say the page is full of text, then changing the position of the image should not change where the text starts and ends, but should just flow around the new position of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help you.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img class="image" src="http://indianapublicmedia.org/stateimpact/files/2013/01/apple-image-300x300.jpg" alt="Apple" />

 <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:200px;
    width:480px;
}

.image
{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/s3bktmcr/)

Comment: That pushes the text and image down. I need the text position to still start at the top.

Comment: @user984003 Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/s3bktmcr/2/)

Comment: If I change the px top of the image, then the text and image moves up. Just the image should move up within the text.