# Image losing its draggability after being dropped

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a div full of text and outside that, an img element. (http://jsfiddle.net/EjP5y/2/) I've made  the image draggable and the div droppable. On the drop event I style the image to have a float:left and add some padding and margins, and then preappend it to the div, so it drops nicely into the div with the div text wrapping around it.

```
$('#clown').draggable();

$('#content').droppable({accept : '#clown', drop : cell_drop});

function cell_drop(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.css({float   : 'left', 
                  padding : '10px', 
                  margin  : '10px',
                  top     : '0', 
                  left    :'0'
                  })
            .prependTo($(this));
```

}

Now, once the image is in the div I'd like to be able to drag it and have the div text flow around the image as the image moves.  The image is draggable, so it seems like I should be able to do this, but it acts like the image lost its draggability when it was dropped into the div, even though Firebug still shows that it has class='ui-draggable'.

Also according to http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ draggables should remain draggables after being dropped.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?  How can I drag the image after it's been dropped in the div and have the div text flow dynamically around the moving image?

Thanks

Comment: it remains draggable after dropping, even though the text doesn't flow around it when you drag after dropping it for once!!!

Comment: Looking a bit harder, I think you're right, it is draggable after being dropped.  But dragging it inside the target and releasing it is actually another drop event for it, so the cell_drop code runs again and puts the image right back at the top, so it doesn't appear to get dragged anywhere. Perhaps I need to kill the droppability of the target after it's received  the image.  Or perhaps I need to prepend the image with top and left values taken from the drop point so it goes in where I dropped it.

Comment: Check out the hack in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9705906/1947286